# Is there a way to invoke python from Windows click?

Tags: python, windows, mouseevent

I have a python app that I'd like to call on some images, by something like this:

- right clicking on images in windows
- menu pops up => shows the python application in the list of items
- when clicked, batch runs on the images

Can this be done w/o using Visual Studio?

Comment: Are you looking for your program to set up this file association as part of its installer or something, or do you just want to do it manually on your computer?

Comment: If it's the latter, that's probably more of a question for Super User than Stack Overflow. But there's an MSDN page for each version of Windows explaining how to do it. For example, Windows 7 uses the ["Default Programs"](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/18539/windows-7-change-default-programs) program to let you configure it.

Comment: Hang on, I'm typing up a long answer (spoiler: it's potentially dangerous and needs the computer's administrator's approval)

Comment: Still typing... Sorry it's taking so long.

Comment: OK I'm done feel free to comment with any questions, I will do my best to answer them

Answer (score 0):

That "list of items" is called the context menu. That is controlled by "The Registry", which is only accessible by the computer's administrator.

MANDATORY WARNING: THE REGISTRY IS **NOT** A TOY, AND **WILL** BREAK YOUR COMPUTER IF YOU DO NOT KNOW WHAT YOU ARE DOING. IF YOU ARE NOT AT LEAST 80% CONFIDENT, **DON'T TOUCH IT**. I TAKE **NO** RESPONSIBILITY IF YOU BREAK YOUR COMPUTER.

That's not to say you will though. If you still want to continue, you should definitely back it up:

1. Open the registry

   1. Press (Windows key) + R to open the run dialog
   2. Type in "regedit.exe" and then enter
   3. Enter you Administrative approval when prompted
2. Once in the registry, look at the panel on the left and all the way at the top there should be a "folder" (called "key" in the registry) called "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT". Click on it. (If you can't find it, it might be under "Computer". Just expand it.). You should now see *a lot* of keys.
3. Backup the registry (optional but recommended)

   1. Click on "File" (top) => "Export".
   2. On the bottom, choose "Selected branch". If you want though, you could export the whole registry by selecting "All" just to be safe (it's a HUGE file though, and probably not necessary)
   3. Choose a file to save it to and click "Save". Wait for the loading to finish.
4. Decide which file type you want. You said: image. That could be: ".jpg", ".png", ".bmp", etc. Just repeat the following steps for all desired file types.
5. Find the "file type association"

   1. Under your selected key, find the key with the file extension you want (eg. ".jpg"). Click on it
   2. There will be a couple of "values" on the side. Check the one called "(Default)". This has the name of the file. (eg: "jpegfile")
6. Navigate to the file. Still in the same key as the extension (".jpg"), locate the key with the name from step 5. Open it.
7. Make a new command.

   1. Right-Click the "shell" key, select "New" => "key"
   2. Name this new key with a logical, one word name (eg "process").
   3. This new key has a "(Default") value. Change it's value (not the name) to what you want to appear on the right click menu.
   4. Under your new key, make a new key called "command".
   5. Set this key's default value to the full path of your Python installation, a space, then the script path, including any arguments. You can pass "%L%" as an argument to have the registry replace it with the path to the right-clicked file. (eg. "path/to/python.exe path/to/script.py %L%"). Just  make sure your Python script can take arguments.

Done!
Feel free to comment with questions

Comment: Unless you're on an old version of Windows (as in pre-XP) where the tools to manage file associations were too weak or broken to be usable, it's a lot easier, and safer, to use those tools than to try to edit the registry yourself.

Comment: The OP did not ask for file association: clicking the file should still open it! Just to add an item in the context menu does need registry editing, as far as I know. And it's not that bad, if you stick to what you know. I have done a lot of work in the registry, like even adding new file types, and it's only dangerous if you start like deleting random stuff.

Comment: File type association is exactly what the OP is asking for. Which is why it's the "file type association" entry in the registry that you're changing in your answer. And, although I don't regularly use Windows, I'm pretty sure that Vista and later all have options to edit the file associations for a type (not just a single entry, but the whole list of entries, and which one is the default for each verb, and all that stuff) in a simple GUI, even if it changes completely and gets a new name with each new version of Windows.

Comment: Right click menu is NOT file association. I need the file association NAME so I know which key's right click menu to edit. If I wanted to change file type association, I could change the name in the extension key's "(default)" value. Or if we were to change the program used to open it, we would change the "open" key in the "shell" key. Adding an item to the right click menu ("In the list of items") is different, and I don't know any (non-shady) programs to do so.